# How do I bring up that initial guided tour panel again?

Tags: software-recommendation

How do I bring up that initial guided tour panel again?  I'm mooking for the panel that starts with "connect your online accounts and then moves on to suggesting different types of linux software.  I really liked some of the suggested apps but since I'm new to linux, I don't remember any of their names.

Comment: @PRATAP im running 18.10

Comment: @PRATAP thanks for the reply.  It appears I don't have permission to change that files permissions.

Comment: @PRATAP That did the trick.  Thank you.  You were right.  It's almost exactly what I was looking for as you were saying.  It's just missing the panels that suggest the different kinds of software you can install.  Regardless, I learned something.  So thank you.

Answer (score 2):

run the below command

```
/usr/lib/gnome-initial-setup/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user
```

[image]