# How can I disable the "Connect your online accounts" dialog, from the command line?

Tags: .desktop

I'm configuring users programatically and I don't want them to see the dialog that asks them to "Connect your online accounts".

Using the command line, how can I prevent this ever coming up?

Using Ubuntu 19.04 desktop

thanks

Comment: See this: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-online-accounts.html.en - If you plan to not use onilne accounts, you can also remove the gnome-online-accounts service with `sudo apt remove --purge gnome-online-accounts`

Answer (score 1):

***Workaround*** - Tested in Ubuntu 19.04

with the help of this post.. https://askubuntu.com/a/1123001/739431

the command that executes the initial setup for Ubuntu 19.04 is `/usr/libexec/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user`

If your question is only to disable **"the dialog that asks them to "Connect your online accounts".** this post is not suitable..

the initial setup is from the package `gnome-initial-setup`

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ apt show gnome-initial-setup
Package: gnome-initial-setup
Version: 3.32.1-1ubuntu3
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers <pkg-gnome-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1,966 kB
Depends: libaccountsservice0 (>= 0.6.24), libc6 (>= 2.29), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libcheese-gtk25 (>= 3.18.0), libcheese8 (>= 3.18.0), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.25.2), libgdm1 (>= 3.8.3), libgeoclue-2-0 (>= 2.4.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.46.0), libgnome-desktop-3-17 (>= 3.17.92), libgoa-1.0-0b (>= 3.5.90), libgoa-backend-1.0-1 (>= 3.10.0), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.22.29), libgweather-3-15 (>= 3.13.91), libibus-1.0-5 (>= 1.5.2), libjson-glib-1.0-0 (>= 0.12.0), libkrb5-3 (>= 1.8+dfsg), libnm0 (>= 1.0.0), libnma0 (>= 1.1.90), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.32.5), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.32.5), libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.99), libpwquality1 (>= 1.1.0), librest-0.7-0 (>= 0.7), libsecret-1-0 (>= 0.18), libsnapd-glib1 (>= 1.42), libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.41.90), libsysmetrics1 (>= 1.0.5), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.5.3), policykit-1 (>= 0.103), adduser, gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.24), gnome-control-center-data
Recommends: gnome-getting-started-docs
Suggests: gdm3
Homepage: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-initial-setup/
Task: ubuntu-desktop-minimal, ubuntu-desktop
Supported: 9m
Download-Size: 1,166 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
Description: Initial GNOME system setup helper
 After acquiring or installing a new system there are a few essential things
 to set up before use. GNOME Initial Setup aims to provide a simple, easy,
 and safe way to prepare a new system.
 .
 GNOME Initial Setup runs the first time you log in to the GNOME desktop
 and lets you easily configure your language, keyboard layout, online accounts
 integration, and more.
 .
 If you want to configure these things at any other time, run the Settings app.

pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

So it is not possible to disable only the `online accounts` dialogue unless one can edit the source files..

Option 1: remove the package - `sudo apt purge gnome-initial-setup`

Option 2: Comment the 5th line which starts with `Exec=` from the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop`

to comment the line, since you mentioned that you want automation, save the below command in your script..

```
sudo sed -i 5d /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop && sudo sed -i '5i#Exec=/usr/libexec/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user' /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop
```

to revert the changes at any time run the below command

```
sudo sed -i 5d /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop && sudo sed -i '5iExec=/usr/libexec/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user' /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop
```

Output of  `nano /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-initial-setup-first-login.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Initial Setup
# Translators: Do NOT translate or transliterate this text (this is an icon file name)!
Icon=preferences-system
Exec=/usr/libexec/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
NoDisplay=true
AutostartCondition=unless-exists gnome-initial-setup-done
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-initial-setup
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=unknown
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-initial-setup
```

Please note that, when the user is newly created and at his first login if the `Exec=` line is `commented`.. the user will not see gnome-initial-setup, however.. If at later stage when the Exec line is `uncommented`.. the user will be shown the `gnome-initial-setup` at his next login for one and only once..